# Retrieve svn update log

Tags: svn

There is some output in console when I'm doing

```
svn update
```

How can I get this output later, when console is closed?

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274272/get-the-previous-svn-update-log/21287421?noredirect=1#21287421

Answer (score 3):

Whatever "console" means in your case, once you've closed the window where `svn update` printed its output the output is gone. If operating systems would routinely store all output of command line programs, you'd soon run out of memory or disk space.

As in all console applications, you can simply redirect output to an external file with the `>` redirection operator:

```
svn update > /path/to/file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Álvaro's answer:

The output from `svn update` just lists the files that were updated in your working copy because of changes in the central SVN repository.

While you cannot get back the output from `svn update` after closing the window, you can look at the recent changes in the repository using `svn log`. This will provide the same information as the log of an update (the only difference being that it also lists older changes, so you should only look at the latest changes).