# Get the previous SVN Update log

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have done an `svn update` from `trunc`. While updating, the Action and corresponding Path had been displayed in `tortoisesvn` dialog box. Once the `update` is done, I have closed the window. My question is how can I review or get the previous `Update` log.I have already done an `svn commit` after my previous `update`.

Comment: I can't think of a good way to get this information again.  You can look at `svn log` but without knowing the state your working copy is in that's not going to help you much.  That's made even more problematic by the fact that your working copy could have mixed revisions.  You can use `svn status` to find out the current state of the working copy (which will show you any conflicts).  But if there were clean updates/merges/deletes you won't see anything there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TortoiseSVN->Settings->Saved Data
```

There's a section at the bottom named `Action log`. Click on the `Show` button to show the log.

Comment: Awesome. I'd dare say you've written TortoiseSVN yourself :)

Comment: File is apparently stored at `%APPDATA%\TortoiseSVN`.

Answer (score 1):

%userprofile%\AppData\Local\TortoiseSVN\logfile.txt