# In TortoiseSVN is there a way to see a log history of what files I updated and when?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The situation is this: I did an SVN update.  But I want to see which files were updated during that most recent update.  Essentially I am looking for a log file that shows all the file system actions timestamped in my local repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the previous SVN Update log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274272/get-the-previous-svn-update-log). Nitpicking: it's called "working copy", not "local repository" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings dialog->Saved Data

Click the `Show` button at the bottom for the `Action log`.